# how to match credential with already hashed password of user in laravel;

Tags: laravel, hash

we know we can get a password as request and then check it with hash which determines whether user is authenticated or not. for example my password from request data is "12345678";

```
$user = User::select('password')->where('email', $request->email)->first();
Hash::check($request->password, $user->password);
```

it gives us a boolean result; but what if the password from request data is already hashed...for example "$2y$10$7slzuQpl8IKB.SOccwF8h.jQnykRyPyX66PtYgzIiYoq2u1AAUl2W"

in this case is there any process by which i can check user validity.?

Comment: You can just check strings equality. `if($request->password == $user->password)`

Comment: Just to point out, you should not be doing this (broadly speaking) if someone somehow gets a hold of your hashed passwords they can just use one to authenticate while they would still need to know the actual password if this were not the case.

Comment: @apokryfos its like my api is a thrid party api for client. in this case the might not want to share actuall password..thats why they want to do the hashing and send request..

Comment: There's more secure ways to do API authentication like OAuth2. Again, just pointing it out, just so you're aware. If you want to keep taking this approach is up to you

Answer (score 0):

If it's already hashed, what about:

```
if($user->password === $request->password)
```

Give you back a boolean

Comment: No.! the hashing doesn't always match with one being stored in database for laravel hash

Comment: So you does something wrong my friend. Where do you get the hashed password from the request?

Comment: lets say a hash password for "12345678" will give you different bcrypted result. i am looking for a way to check whether both of these are same.both of these in a sense the one from request and the one which is stored in db. .and as u asked where did i get, lets say another developer will already do the hashing and send it to my api

Comment: I think it is not possible, laravel use keys to hash. So the other developper should send if it is matching or not. So you don't need to check on your side. Otherwise I don't see. Sharing the keys is very very bad for the security. It is even better he send you the password and you hash it to put in your database

Comment: yeah i know that. .it's upon clients demand. but anyway what keys you are talking about.?? as i know they use salt which gives different result every time u do hahing.

Comment: Yes it is what I thought but you say it does not work... So I thought it uses the salts keys also

Answer (score 0):

By default, Laravel currently uses `bcrypt` algorithm for hashing.

In PHP a random salt is provided to anything you hash. Meaning if you were to have the same thing multiple times, it can give different results. This is to prevent security risks, such as Rainbow table attacks, where someone can lookup your hashed value, and find the original value.

Therefore it is NOT possible to do something like this:

```
$user = User::where('password', $hashedPassword)->first();
```

See:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php